# How will a branch off a branch look like when I do git branch -a?

Tags: git, github, branch

If I do "git branch -a" in my terminal, does a branch of a branch (so a branch I made off of another branch) look different from a branch off of origin?
For example, if I have a branchB off of branchA, should the branch look like: origin/branchA/branchB?

Comment: git branch will just print out your local branches.  git branch -a will print out local branches and remote branches.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: that's what I wanted to do: look at all my branches. My question had nothing to do with the command or what it does.

Comment: Sorry about that. I misread your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons `branchB` does *not* appear as `branchA/branchB` are:

- that would imply some kind of strong coupling between `branchA` and `branchB`, which makes no sense considering:

  - `branchA` can be deleted at any time (that won't delete the commits it referenced): `branchB` would still be there, unchanged
  - `branchB` can be [rebased](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) at any time on top of any other branch
  - `branchB` has no knowledge of any other branch it is "based" upon: it only references a commit (and all commits reachable from its HEAD)
- a slash is allowed in a branch name: you can name it `xxx/yyy` (as *one* branch): this is for defining a [hierarchy in a branch naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309).
  Typical examples:

  - [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) branches for review: `refs/for/REL1_20/bug/36151`: the `for/REL1_20/bug/36151` is one (Gerrit) branch.
  - [GitHub Pull Request branches](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally): `git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME`: `pull/ID` is one (PR) branch

Answer (score 2):

No.

Unless you name it that, anyway. All that is displayed is the branch's name, which can be anything you want.