# Does creating a GIT branch in 2 different ways give the same result? How to do this with worktree?

Tags: git

Lets say I create a GIT branch like this:

```
git clone <main repository>
cd <main repository>
git checkout develop
git branch test/udp_client
git checkout test/udp_client
```

Or like this:

```
git clone <main repository>
cd <main repository>
git branch develop/test/udp_client
git checkout develop/test/udp_client
```

**Question A:** Is the end result the same?

---

**Question B:** How would I do this using `git worktree`?

Comment: For Question A: the end results are *usually* the same. Except that the result is not what you expect; the result of `git checkout develop` is not used in `git branch test/udp_client` the way you expect so the end result is branch `test/udp_client`, not `develop/test/udp_client`. The new branch initially points to the same commit as `develop`; these 2 commands can be combined into one: `git branch test/udp_client develop`. All 3 commands can be combined into one: `git checkout -b test/udp_client develop`.

Comment: But in your case there is major problem: once you have a branch `develop` you cannot create a branch `develop/test/udp_client`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527452/7976758

Comment: @phd It would be really nice if you could draw an image and post an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step comparing the 2 code blocks. Block №1:

```bash
git checkout develop
git branch test/udp_client
git checkout test/udp_client
```

What it does: it checks out (or create from remote) branch `develop`. It creates a new branch `test/udp_client` (but not `develop/test/udp_client`; the name of the current branch is not used in creating a new branch) pointing to the same commit as the current branch (the current is `develop`). Then it checks out the new branch. The last 2 commands in the block can be combined into one command: `git checkout -b test/udp_client`. Branch `develop` is not required to be the currently checked out branch — the command  `git checkout -b test/udp_client develop` creates a new branch pointing to the same commit as `develop` and checks out the new branch; so the command replaces all 3.

The second block

```bash
git branch develop/test/udp_client
git checkout develop/test/udp_client
```

is very similar. If we ignore the existence of branch `develop` in the repository what the block does is: it creates a new branch `develop/test/udp_client` pointing to the same commit as the current branch; the current branch is not necessary `develop`, it's most probably `main` or `master`. Then the code checks out the new branch.

Unfortunately there is already branch `develop` so the 2nd block fails with cryptic error message "fatal: Failed to lock ref for update: Not a directory" or "fatal: Failed to lock ref develop/test/udp_client for update: branch develop already exists". The problem is slashes are used in branch names exactly as path separators: branches are stored as files and branches with slashes are stored as directories with the leaf (last path component) as a file. You cannot have `develop` both as a directory and a file at the same time. I.e., if you have branch `develop` you cannot create `develop/test/udp_client` and vice versa — if you have branch `develop/test/udp_client` you cannot create branch `develop`.

I cannot answer Question B as I don't use worktrees — I use a lot of submodules and worktrees are incompatible with submodules so I just use separate clones.

Comment: Thank you. The part: *"Branches are stored as files and branches with slashes are stored as directories with the last path component stored as a file. You cannot have `develop` both as a directory and a file at the same time. Therefore if you have branch `develop` you cannot create `develop/test/udp_client` and vice versa."* made it clear.